# I can not see my documents in MongoDB Atlas even can see my database and collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have been facing this problem and trying to fix it but can not so far.

I connected MongoDB Atlas successfully. I can see my database and collections, however I can not see the documents in the collections.

I don't know what is the problem. I got very frustrated because I have been working on it since one week :(:(

Any help would be highly appreciated!

I checked database and network accesses.
I checked my user name and the password.
I tethered my phone as well.

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

async function main () {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/needHelpNow', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}      
main()
```

In .env file, I have DB_URI which is

```
DB_URI=mongodb+srv://<my user name>:<my password>@cluster0.pityslz.mongodb.net/needHelpNow?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
```

Comment: Are they visible in mongodb cloud? If yes, then they should be visible in atlas

Comment: Have you given the DB name? If yes, have you given then DB name also, in the mongodb URI?

Comment: yes, I gave the database name in the string provided by atlas. what do you mean by the cloud? Atlas is not cloud? @Sandeep M

Comment: Is the connection being established? and if possible show the code so that I can dig into it deep.

Comment: It says 'connected' in my console. I will be sharing the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dreamer Apologies, I meant mongodb compass. If it is visible in atlas(cloud) then it should be in compass

Comment: In MongoDB compass, I can see documents I created. I can not see them in Atlas.

Comment: @Dreamer as I can see you have just made the connection. You need to query the documents in order to get created.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. If I am wrong please correct me because my knowledge is limited. I use mongoose to achieve CRUD operations. Do you mean this or something else which I do not have any idea?

Comment: Also, I have tried to insert a document using mongoshell. It was created but I can only see this document in Atlas not the old ones I had created before using Atlas service.

Comment: @Dreamer I cannot add the solution over here. I don't know why but, here is the link to the demo code that you can try if this resolves your issue.

https://codeshare.io/LjjVYg

Comment: Many thanks @JuzarAntri. I will try the code soon.